# FileNotFoundException when restarting the app

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I don't know why but I get an FileNotFoundException from my Init() function.

What's happening is, when I launch the app for the first time, it's normal to get one (the file does not exist). Then I press a button which calls Save and so creates the file (if I add a Log just after outputStream.close(), I'm able to see it). I actually tried to open the created file with a FileInputStream and I didn't get the exception.

But. When I close the app and open it again. I get the FileNotFoundException. Any idea why ?

```
public class MyClass {
    public static Context mContext ;    
    public static void Save(){
        String test = "test" ;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(test.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void Init(Context c){
        mContext = c ;
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = c.openFileInput(FILENAME);
            String test = "";
            char ch ;
            while((ch=(char) inputStream.read())!=-1)
                test+= ch ;
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit :

So, those calls are not in an activity but in a static class. `Init` is called from `onCreate` of my main activity. `Save` is called from `onPause` of another activity. Hope that helps.

Comment: If Your Activity is not too big, show the complete code, maybe the issue is anywhere else...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs hope the edit helps

Comment: You should provide Save() with its own context like Save(Context context). Do not make void functions but let them return a boolean true/false so the caller knows if all went well. Further you can avoid file not found exceptions by using `File file = new File(fileName); if ( !file.exists()) return false;`.

Comment: The fact is, I'm not really trying to avoid the exception but rather to understand why I get it (why my file is not found, it's supposed to be here)